# Understand the solution to printing the reverse of a Linked List with recursion

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

This is the question I'm working on: Print reverse of a Linked List without actually reversing.

Here is a link to the answer provided by [GeeksforGeeks:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-reverse-of-a-linked-list-without-actually-reversing/)

I've been looking at what happens step by step with the IntelliJ debug tool but still don't understand how it works.I see that we iterate through the list until the very end and somehow the function starts going backward after we pass the last node? How?Could someone explain this to me please?

```
    void printReverse(Node head)
    {
        if (head == null) return;
 
        // print list of head node
        printReverse(head.next);
 
        // After everything else is printed
        System.out.print(head.data+" ");
    }
```

Comment: The actual `println(...)`ing happens "on the way up" (i.e. when the recursion unwinds).

Comment: Fundamentally, I think you don't understand what "returning from a routine (function, method)" actually means for the flow of control.

Comment: @accessviolation Got an article/resource to read more about that?

Comment: @FNZ the thing is that in this method, whenever the `System.out.print` line is reached, its call to `printReverse` was already evaluated. The algorithm starts by passing the (real) head of the list, the very first element. This element should be printed last. So, how is this reached? The method calls itself for the second element and whatever this second call does, the printing happens AFTER it did its work. This is why the very first element is displayed for the last. Because everything else happens before its printing.

Comment: And then think about the second element as the head of a sublist. It's passed to the second call and we already know that the first element is printed after the second element's call was evaluated (and printed). So, the second method call does a third call for the method, WAITS FOR IT and only then prints. This is why the second element is displayed AFTER any other element, except the first. and this logic is repeated over and over again, ultimately reaching a displaying of reversed order.

Comment: There is no article. 'return' (or falling off the end of the routine) returns to the point just after the call.

Answer (score 3):

The logic of the recursion is called post-order, in which you define your logic after the recursion call

Assume you have the following LinkedList 1->2->3->null

And you call

```
printReverse(head)
```

- **First** will check if the head is null, if yes return (stop don't continue execution)
- **Second**  call `printReverse` by pointing to the next node
- **Third** repeat steps 1 & 2 until hitting the null node
- **Four** print the data

The result will print from the last node to the first node

[image]

Comment: As stated in your diagram as well, we call print when the head is null. So how are we printing the last node instead of null? and how are we iterating backward to print the rest?

Comment: When the head is null the condition will match then return stop recursion

Comment: The print will be from the last to the first, so we print the LinkedList in reverse order

Comment: There is no "iterating backwards".  Each time printReverse returns (either explicitly or by falling off the end of the method) it returns to its immediate caller, which may be the previous level of printReverse, just after the call (of course) and therefore the next thing it executes is the print,

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand this, you need to understand the concept of LIFO (**L**ast **I**n, **F**irst **O**ut).

This is the basic concept for a data structured called the stack, which is of great relevance in our case, because the memory section where function calls are being stored is called **the stack**, because it operates as a stack.

Let's see your method:

```
    void printReverse(Node head)
    {
        if (head == null) return;
 
        // print list of head node
        printReverse(head.next);
 
        // After everything else is printed
        System.out.print(head.data+" ");
    }
```

Initially this is called by passing the very first node of your linked list. By the way, let's imagine that your linked list has n elements, of the form of

l(1) -> l(2) -> ... -> l(n) -> null

The i'th call to `printReverse` checks whether `head` is `null`, which, if true, then we have reached the end of the list.

Now, here's what happens:

We reach l(1), which calls `printReverse` for l(2) and waits for it to complete before printing the value of l(1). The call for `printReverse`, on l(2), on its turn calls `printReverse` on l(3) and waits for it to complete, before completing and so on. Once the stack is fully built and we reach the `null`, then the n+1'th function call returns without a print. Then, the n'th call finishes the `printReverse` line and prints and so on.

For illustration, let's consider the following list:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null

This is what happens:

- calling `printReverse` for the first item

  - is the node (the first one) `null`? No
  - calling `printReverse` for the second item

    - is the node (the second one) `null`? No
    - calling `printReverse` for the third item

      - is the node (the third one) `null`? No
      - calling `printReverse` for the fourth (nonexistent) item

        - is the node (the `null` after the last element) `null`? Yes, do nothing
      - printing 3
    - printing 2
  - printing 1

As you can see, each function call is a level deeper than the former function call and the former function call waits for the functions it called to evaluate. Since it prints after its function calls, this means that when the method reaches the print of a level, all inner levels were already evaluated and printed, reaching the reversed order.